# Invalid Column name asp

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, sqlcommand

This is my first time creating a web api from scratch and I'm trying to get a selected value in a drop down bow to trigger an sql search and make the appropriate item appear in a text box. below is the relevant code

```
protected void btnRetrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string pNameTemp = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

            myConnection.Open();
            string query = ("SELECT sName from [dbo].[Table] WHERE (pName LIKE " + pNameTemp + ")");
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);                
            txtSkill.Text = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            myConnection.Close();
        }

    catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

it seems to search the correct name but when it comes to updating the txtSkill, I get the exception 'invalid column name' pop up, are there any obvious reasons as to why this is happening that i'm missing? any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You just need to wrap the value in quotes, inside the query...  `"SELECT sName from [dbo].[Table] WHERE (pName LIKE '" + pNameTemp + "')"`  (notice the single quotes before and after `" + pNameTemp + "`)

Comment: You should look into using a parameter in the query. As it is your code could leave you vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.

Comment: Did you name your databas table `Table`? Start by renaming it to a better name. And your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Better use parametarized queries.

Comment: Cheers guys, whilst this has stopped the exception from happening, the text box itself still isn't displaying anything,  do you know any reasons as to why?

Comment: @SBFrancies In this particular case it is probably that default ViewState data checking could avoid SQL Injection, but as general rule your warning is positive.

Comment: You may need to put `%` (SQL text matching wildcards) before and/or after the string that you want to match.

Comment: @Jackington Your `LIKE` clause is missing the `%`. `FieldName LIKE '%" + pNameTemp + "%'` should work. BTW check the parametrized queries comments to avoid future security problems.

Comment: Got it working now cheers for all the help, up votes for you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you are missing `''` for the parameter of the query.

Try to use this query.

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT sName from [dbo].[Table] WHERE pName LIKE '{pNameTemp}'", myConnection);
```

But I recommend you to use `SqlParameter` in C# to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT sName from [dbo].[Table] WHERE pName LIKE @field", myConnection);
myConnection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", pNameTemp);
```

But normally, when we use `LIKE`, we should put in `%` because it gives all results contains `keyword`. `LIKE` without `%` doesn't make sense. So :

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT sName from [dbo].[Table] WHERE pName LIKE @field", myConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", "'%" + pNameTemp + "%'");
```

There are [some options](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) in the `LIKE` clause:

- %: The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters
- _ The underscore represents a single character

Comment: @Archer Sr, my preference is write down the answer and perfect it.

Comment: That's okay - you've added more so now it's a good answer and worthy of upvoting :)

Comment: Added an edit proposal with a bit of extra info on the `LIKE` clause